# I wrote a code for RCBAM in tensor flow and its not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

This is RCBAM class which i have added in my model

```
    def __init__(self, channels):
        super(RCBAM, self).__init__()

        self.channel_attention = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(channels, activation='relu'),  # Match channels
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(channels, activation='sigmoid')  # Match channels
        ])

        self.spatial_attention = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=channels, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', activation='sigmoid')
        ])
    def call(self, inputs):
        channel_attention = self.channel_attention(inputs)
        spatial_attention = self.spatial_attention(inputs)

        attention = channel_attention * spatial_attention

        # Resize the attention tensor to match the shape of the inputs tensor
        attention = tf.image.resize(attention, size=(7, 7), method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)

        # Multiply the attention tensor element-wise with inputs to apply attention
        attended_inputs = inputs * attention

        return attended_inputs




resnet = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3), 
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet'
)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(resnet)



model.add(RCBAM(channels=3))


model.add(tf.keras.layers.DilatedConv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), dilation_rate=2, activation='relu'))


model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

i made the model using resnet50 as mentioned in the above code and i want to add rcbam to my model but i am getting some unusual error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[54], line 1
----> 1 model.add(RCBAM(channels=3))
      3 # Add the PAM attention mechanism
      4 model.add(PAM(model))

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py:587, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    585 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    586 try:
--> 587   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    588 finally:
    589   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File /var/folders/8n/95vlvnl93lg2r18pnsrgf8f40000gn/T/__autograph_generated_fileiwgh9i4m.py:14, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call(self, inputs)
     12 attention = ag__.ld(channel_attention) * ag__.ld(spatial_attention)
     13 attention = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).image.resize, (ag__.ld(attention),), dict(size=(7, 7), method=ag__.ld(tf).image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR), fscope)
---> 14 attended_inputs = ag__.ld(inputs) * ag__.ld(attention)
     15 try:
     16     do_return = True

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "rcbam_16" (type RCBAM).

in user code:

    File "/var/folders/8n/95vlvnl93lg2r18pnsrgf8f40000gn/T/ipykernel_14333/1495175677.py", line 25, in call  *
        attended_inputs = inputs * attention

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2048 and 3 for '{{node rcbam_16/mul_1}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](Placeholder, rcbam_16/resize/ResizeBilinear)' with input shapes: [?,7,7,2048], [?,7,7,3].


Call arguments received by layer "rcbam_16" (type RCBAM):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 7, 7, 2048), dtype=float32)
```

so while adding RCBAM attention i am getting this error.
can anyone solve it?

As far as i know there is something wrong with my rcbam class.

I was expecting to run this code but got this error

so my code is in tensorflow and its not working